# Quarkus/PostgreSQL/Listener - Unable to acquire JDBC Connection ("Sorry, acquisition timeout")

Tags: postgresql, quarkus

I am using Quarkus/PostgreSQL and it is working fine with no errors (jdb config min-size and max-size default). When I added a listener to an entity just to set the user (with annotations @PrePersist and @Preupdate) I noticed the following errors in the log:

```
stackTrace: "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: 
Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Sorry, acquisition timeout!
    at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool.handlerFromSharedCache(ConnectionPool.java:282)
```

These errors appears a lot because I believe, probably have transactions opened and never closely (list method) causing timeout due to no connections available. But my question is why this happens only after I added this listener. I didn't know that a listener could cause this error since I only perform, inside prepersist/preupdate methods the user set (apply user for two fields like createdby, updatedby). By the way, what's the difference of using the @preupdate @prepersist callback methods directly on the entity instead of creating a listener? I know that if I create a Listener class, it can be used for different entities. But for this case, if I only use the callback methods inside the entity, it will make difference to avoid the error mentioned above?

Default config:
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size (default 20)

Information about app:
quarkus-universe-bom 1.10.2.Final
PostgreSQL 9.6
Java 8

Regards,
Bortolon

Comment: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9123#issuecomment-735418161 looks like same issue. they like to have a reproducer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue adding the methods with preupdate and prepersist directly inside Entity, not using a a Listener.